# why does my csv contain a different format than my script

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I wrote some code to standardize the format of the date of a CSV. The first column can contain two different time formats: 06/13/20 and 06.13.2020

I want all data to look like 06/13/20.

```
with open(fileread) as f:
    readCSV = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for row in readCSV:
        try:
            datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%m.%d.%Y') # get date
            datetime_object = datetime_object.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
            print(datetime_object)
            save = datetime_object
        except:
            save = row[0]
        with open(filewrite, '+a', newline='') as g:
            out = [save, row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]]
            writer = csv.writer(g, delimiter=';')
            print(out)
            writer.writerow(out)
```

note: I used "save" cause I thought there would be some kind of formatting be saved in `row[0]`. I tried it with `row[0]` instead of save and it had no other effect.

So my terminal output for "out" looks like this:

```
['06/02/20',...]
```

but in the CSV it's still `06.13.2020`

Comment: You are using the append mode in the file opening line (marked by 'a' in '+a'), so your corrected format lines are appended instead of overwriting.

Comment: Small suggestion: You don't need to open the output file and create the CSV writer every time. I'd move it outside of the for loop. That way you do not need the apped as @DavidWierichs pointed out.

Comment: yeah ok, i move it outside, but to david: there are no right lines in the new file, so they arent appended, they dont exist

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

I moved the code that opens the output file and creates the CSV writer outside the for loop. `strptime` throws `ValueError` if the supplied string does not match the provided format, therefore I narrowed the catch.

You have to check if you really want the append on the second line. Check the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for the available open modes.

```py
with open(fileread) as f:
    with open(filewrite, '+a', newline='') as g:
        readCSV = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
        writer = csv.writer(g, delimiter=';')
        for row in readCSV:
            save = row[0]
            try:
                datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%m.%d.%Y') # get date
                save = datetime_object.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
            except ValueError:
                pass
            out = [save, row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]]
            print(out)
            writer.writerow(out)
```

Edit: Missed indentation of last three rows

After the fix I tested with the following input:

```
06.13.2020;a;b;c;d
7/2/00;a;b;c;d
```

and got

```
06/13/20;a;b;c;d
7/2/00;a;b;c;d
```

Comment: That code not only writes just one line, the format is still the same..

Comment: Sorry, I falsely indented  the last three lines there. They belong into the for loop obviously ;)

Comment: mhh.. maybe there is some kind of hidden format in "row" because if i open that file in excel, its still in the wrong format. the right lines are formated as "standard" and the wrong ones with"date"..

Comment: Try opening the file in a text editor, not Excel. This will show you the real content of the file.

Comment: Excel interprets the data and tries to guess the content. I think there is an option to ignore cell types while importing CSV data. If you need Excel to show it correctly, you can try selecting the whole column and set the cell type manually to "Date".